# How to convert FormatMessage output to an Java Exception message in JNI under windows?

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, visual-c++

I am trying to convert Windows error to an java IOException with the fuciont below:

```
void ThrowIOException(JNIEnv * env, LPCTSTR lpszFunction, DWORD dw) 
{ 
LPVOID lpMsgBuf;

FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    NULL,
    dw,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
    0, NULL );


//    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 



jclass Exception = env->FindClass("java/io/IOException");
if(env->ThrowNew(Exception, (const char *)lpDisplayBuf)){
    printf("Can't throw IOException: %s\n", lpDisplayBuf);
}


LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}
```

I am using Unicode in my VC project. The IOException throws successfully, but the message in 'lpDisplayBuf' is not displayed properly.

I am aware of that casting lpDisplayBuf to "const char *" might be wrong, but I don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

If your VC project is setup as UNICODE then you need to convert the string returned from FormatMessage to ANSI as in the following example (please, note  that I put **no** error checking at all)

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "jni.h"
#include 

extern "C" 
{
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_jnihellowworld_sayIt(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
    {
        jclass excClass;
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
        char buffer[1000];

        FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL,
            2,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
            0, NULL );

        excClass = env->FindClass("java/io/IOException");

        ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 
                        0, 
                        (LPCWSTR) lpMsgBuf, 
                        -1, 
                        buffer, 
                        1000, 
                        NULL, 
                        NULL);

        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
        env->ThrowNew(excClass, buffer);

        return env->NewStringUTF("never reached");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not readly working, but I get the idea. I give up and use MultiByte in my VC project And make FormatMessage alway return errors in English.

Comment: Why not working? What's happening? It worked on my machine :)

Comment: I am not sure. The message from IOException is corruptd. Maybe the system error message returned from FormatMessage is not UTF. I have limited knowledge on Windows programming....